# Application shortcut reappears on restart

Tags: .net, installation, shortcut

I have an application that I have built a .msi installer for throgh Microsoft Visual Studio 2010. I recently made some updates, including changing the version number and rebuilt the installer with these updates. The installer includes shortcuts on both the desktop and in the Start menu. Running the installer appears to work fine, and both of these shortcuts work. After restarting my computer I've found that the shortcuts are changed to have a Target type of Application (Installs on first use) and the Start In: field is changed to a location that doesn't exist. Once this happens, every time you use that shortcut it tries to install the application again and fails.

I have also changed the name of the shortcut that the installer creates. This appears to work, and the shortcut still works after a restart. After the restart, though, the shortcut with the old name that doesn't work also appears on the desktop and in the Start menu.

Does anyone have any ideas what I may have set up wrong, or what I need to change to get the shortcuts to be have properly?

Comment: This seems better suited for SO.  It's not a white board problem (Programmers main domain) and is looking for an implementation result (SO main domain). But SO would need a lot more detail in the question to be useful.

Comment: I debated on if it should go here or in SO and landed here because it appears to be something with the installer ... or at least taht's my latest theory. How do I transfer it? I'd also be glad to provide aditional information if someone can let me know what would be helpful.

Comment: My suggestion would be to edit your question here and once you have the detail, flag it asking a moderator to migrate it for you.  That will give the mods a chance to see your edit and if there's enough to survive on SO.

Comment: Thanks for the help Walter I think I have the issue resolved, but I appreciate the suggestions you gave me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appear to have this issue resolved ... even though I'm not sure if I understand what caused it or what solved it. In the end, I created a new Solution file and built the project from that new solution. I don't understand why that would make a difference, and comparing the new and old solution files they changes don't appear to be significant. After doing this, though, the installer build from this solution appears to be working correctly.

I should also note that I deleted the deployment project and created a new one. Doing this did not appear to have an affect on the issue, but the new deployment project was included with the new solution.